# OpenMP for loop cause wrong result

Tags: visual-c++, floating-point, openmp, reduction

I want to compare the loop performance with openmp by part of simple code. But the result is wrong.

I already use reduction to avoid race condition but never work.

here is my code: thanks for any suggestion

```
void TestMP_1(){
    float afValueTmp[MP_TEST_NUM] = { 0 }; // MP_TEST_NUM = 10000
    float sum = 0, sumNoMP = 0;
    float fDiff = 0;
    double eTDiff = 0;
    double t0 = 0;
    double t1 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MP_TEST_NUM; i++)
    {
        afValueTmp[i] = i;
    }

    t0 = (double)getTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < MP_TEST_NUM; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < MP_TEST_NUM; k++);  // just for delay

        sumNoMP += afValueTmp[i];   // equation 4
    }

    t0 = ((double)getTickCount() - t0) / getTickFrequency();
    t1 = (double)getTickCount();

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction( +:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < MP_TEST_NUM; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < MP_TEST_NUM; k++);  // just for delay

        sum += afValueTmp[i];
    }

    t1 = ((double)getTickCount() - t1) / getTickFrequency();
    eTDiff = t0 - t1;   // time improve
    fDiff = sum - sumNoMP;  // check result
    printf("%.3f\n", eTDiff);
}
```

Comment: `for (int k = 0; k < MP_TEST_NUM; k++)   // just for delay` do you want that to be an empty loop? Then you need a `;` at end.

Comment: @ Johnny Mopp thanks for notice. but after adding ";" for the delay loop. the result still miss match.

Comment: I manual calculate the result is   49995000
and sumNoMP = 49992896 sum = 49994736.....

Comment: If you wish to avoid rounding you could use double

Comment: Consider using Kahan summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing floating point accuracy issues. Please allow me to elaborate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float myOrigNumber = 49995000;
    float myNumber = myOrigNumber + 1.;

    printf ("orig: %f new: %f diff: %f\n",
            myOrigNumber, myNumber, myNumber-myOrigNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

The result will be:

```
orig: 49995000.000000 new: 49995000.000000 diff: 0.000000
```

So, where did that `+1` go?

The `float` type only has 7 to 8 significant digits. It doesn't matter where they are, because floats are internally always represented in [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) as x.xxE+yy notation, where x.xx has 24 bits and yy has 8 bits.
The number 49995001 is larger than 2^24 (16,777,216), so it will be rounded to the closest number that can be accurately represented, which apparently is 49995000.

This is why using `double` for `sum` will alleviate your pain. It's not a real solution, though. Reduction operations have the requirement that the operation must be *commutative*. 
But that's not necessarily the case for floating point addition: if you add hundred times 1 and then 49995000 to `sum`, the result will be different from when you first add 1 and 49995000, and then ninety-nine times 1: in the second case, every later +1 will be rounded down as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Your results may be correct according to what you have written and expected rounding.

Comment: the number in afValueTmp[i]  is all interger and 49995000 is not over float type range. why there are rounding issue, making result different?

I find that once I use double type for sum & sumNoMP, all result will be right.